# Where is the XPATH query actually entered when querying an xml document using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to xml database, and have read many tutorials on querying xml files. Yet not a single one of these tutorials tells you WHERE to actually enter the query information. For example, w3schools goes into alot of detail on how to write query path expressions, but NOTHING on where to enter the thing!!

(NONE of these tutorial sites say where to actually enter the query. They just go on and on talking about these xml path queries, show endless examples, but never say WHERE DO YOU ACTUALLY ENTER THE QUERY????  I don't get how these guys can write all these tutorials and miss the most obvious thing that a newcomer needs to know! Thanks.)

Comment: You mention "xml database" - **WHICH** database would that be??

Comment: I'm talking about making a native xml database from scratch. I'm looking at doing this to evolve away from mysql because of the schema flexibility (similar to eav relational model), object orientation, and text format versus being buried in mysql app.

Answer (score 2):

**XPath is not a stand-alone language -- it is always hosted by a host programming language** -- such as C#, Java, VB, PHP, ..., etc.

The program written in a particular PL needs to follow the rules for evaluating XPath expressions within that PL. Typically, there is an XPath-oriented API that provides a set of objects and functions for doing so. Often, an XPath expression that selects nodes is passed as a parameter to one function, while an XPath expression the result of whose evaluation isn't a set of nodes (e.g. a string or a number) is passed as a parameter to another function.

For example, in C# one can use the `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` methods of `XmlDocument`, `XmlNode`, `XPathDocument` -- for selecting a set of nodes or a single node -- and the `Evaluate()` method of `XPathDocument` to evaluate any type of XPath expression (not only one that selects node(s)).

**Among the hosts of XPath, two are notably different: XSLT and XQuery fully integrate XPath** -- they use XPath natively -- it is a part of the language, so no explicit XPath evaluation functions need to be called in these two languages. The developer isn't required to be distracted by having to switch between two different worlds: the PL world and the XPath world.

**XPath is a naturally integrated part part of the XSLT/XQuery world**.

In my experience XSLT and/or XQuery are the languages in which using XPath is most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You do it via XPath functions in whatever language you're writing in to manipulate the XML file. e.g. in PHP you'd be using PHPDom to load the xml file, and then DOMXPath to do the queries.

Telling you "where to write" xpath would be pointless. XPath is not a programming language. It's a syntax definition for finding data in an XML file. It has no i/o capabilities whatsoever, it simply tells an XML library what to look for. How you access that xml library is outside XPath's perview.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thought I'd check this out as a simpler alternative to php/mysql for light-duty applications, but this doesn't look like it would save much implementation work versus just sticking to php/mysql.

Comment: OK, I finally understand this. Similar to accessing mysql with php.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. PHP doesn't understand anything about sql. But you use php to generate sql and send it to the database. Similarly, you don't "use" xpath, you just write an xpath expression which is sent to some engine to evaluate and (hopefully) return some results.